# java - remove object from map/array collection if it exists

Tags: java

Players are added to an array

```
Player[] players = new Player[]
```

A hashmap is created in another class

```
private Map <String, Player> players; 

players = new HashMap<String, Player>();
```

Then players are added to the collection

```
public void addPlayer(Player player) {
  players.put(player.getPlayerId(), player); 
}
```

Need to write a method that removes a player if they existed and returen true/false

```
public boolean removePlayer(Player player)
```

So far I have:

```
public boolean removePlayer(Player player) {
  //check player key exists, returns true/false
  if (players.containsKey(player.getPlayerId())){
     players.remove(player.getPlayerId());
     return true;
  }
  else
     return false;
}
```

Will this work? how can I test it?

Comment: What makes you think this won't work?

Comment: just my newbie anxiety

Comment: Well rest assured, it'll work :). This doesn't mean you shouldn't unit-test it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good approach to write an unit test (jUnit, testNG) to check the particular methods. It will improve overall quality of your code and you will be sure it works as designed.

Even more if you change the code, the test will tell if something become wrong less than in a second.